# Why p5js skethch integrated with Vaadin won't start?

Tags: javascript, java, vaadin, p5.js

I'm trying to integrate a p5js with the Vaadin. The goal is to plug p5js library and my p5js Sketch as well into the Vaadin's view component. So I would be able to launch and render my a p5js Sketch on client side and refer to some logic on the server side.

As I am figuring out once p5js library loaded it would start automaticaly (The p5js library is a script file with a main function inside round brakets) and catch my "setup()" and "draw()" functions from sketch. And this is exactly how it works if I make an empty html page and plug scripts there with  tags.

In Vaadin I used @JavaScript annotation for both scripts and start localhost but hothing happens. Sketch won't start. There is test "console.log()" inside "setup()" function it won't works off too.

Also somehow I can't reach the sketch's functions from browser's console (Neither just "setup()", nor "window.setup()", nor "p5.setup() fit) but with tiny code modification I can. If I place my sketch code inside "window.ns={// my code}" I can refer to it via "window.ns..." in the console. So I'm pretty sure sketches are loaded with page.

What am I missing?

Here is Vaadin's view class I've made (Java):

```
@Route(value = "/MyView")
@JavaScript("p5.js")
@JavaScript("sketch.js")
public class MyView extends VerticalLayout {
    public MyView() {
    }
}
```

Here is the Sketch's code (JavaScript):

```
 function setup () {
    console.log(`test message`);
    createCanvas(400, 400);
}
 function draw () {
    background(220);
}
```

There is no any error message relevant to the issue. The console is silent.

Update:

Also it might be useful if someone experienced look at the high-levevel library code to figure out how it starts:
[high-levevel library code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdn5V.png)

Answer (score 0):

The content of the JavaScript is not automatically executed. You need to add JavaScript call in your view, something like.

```
@Route(value = "/MyView")
@JavaScript("./p5.js")
@JavaScript("./sketch.js")
public class MyView extends VerticalLayout {
    public MyView() {
        getElement().executeJs("setup();draw();");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Tatu. To convince myself that JavaScript do automaticly execute I create an empty html with minimal code inside with script tags to both files`<script src="p5.js"></script> <script src="sketch.js"></script>`. It started automaticaly and runs perfectly. Also the invocation in MyView constructor `getElement().executeJs("console.log(test)");` also works. But the suggested `getElement().executeJs("setup()");` doesn't work with error messge "Uncaught ReferenceError: setup is not defined" in console.

Comment: In which scope those functions hace been defined? Do you need to call them using window.setup()?

Comment: Here above is the code of script within "setup()" function with no any additional scope or name space defenition. I'm just plug it with @JavaScript annotation. But I'm not so experienced in JavaScript. How can I check in wich scope scripts works? 
"window.setup()" in console lead to the error "Uncaught TypeError: window.setup is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:8"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like p5 works the other way around and you need to load the sketch *before* p5. See https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Global-and-instance-mode#when-is-global-mode-assumed

This can lead to problems and confusion down the road when mixing other JS libraries or trying to embed multiple p5 sketches on the same page. So it is better to use "instance mode".

Here is example using `@NpmPackage` in Vaadin:

```
 @Route("/p5demo")
 @NpmPackage(value = "p5", version = "1.8.0")
 @JsModule("./mySketch.js")
 public class P5Demo extends Div {
 
   Div demo = new Div();
 
   public P5Demo() {
     demo.getElement().executeJs("initMySketch(this)");
     add(demo);
   }
 }
```

And in `frontend/mySketch.js` you should import `p5` and define the `window.initMySketch`:

```
import p5 from 'p5'

const mySketch = (sketch) => {

  sketch.setup = () => {
    sketch.createCanvas(400, 400, sketch.WEBGL);
  };

  sketch.draw = () => {
    sketch.background(250);
    sketch.normalMaterial();
    sketch.push();
    sketch.translate(0, -100, 0);
    sketch.rotateZ(sketch.frameCount * 0.01);
    sketch.rotateX(sketch.frameCount * 0.01);
    sketch.rotateY(sketch.frameCount * 0.01);
    sketch.box(70, 70, 70);
    sketch.pop();
  };
}

/* This is visible to to getElement().executeJs(...) method. */
window.initMySketch = (el) => { new p5(mySketch, el); }
```

Note: This example is using Vaadin's `@JsModule` and it will result a frontend build every time you your sketch.